# how to show minus currency in brackets with currency sign

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have variable which is negative numbers after $ sign (actually it shows currency with currency sign). Please tell me how to show minus currency in brackets with currency sign. I mean to say how to change var val=($125,220,328.00)

My code is looks like this

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}


function netAmount(){
    var net_amount =0;
    $('#productList tr:gt(1)').each(function() {
        var row_index= $(this).index();
        var qty= $('#productList tr:eq('+row_index+') td input[name="quantity"]').val().replace( /[^0-9\.]/g, '' );
        var price= $('#productList tr:eq('+row_index+') td input[name="purchase_price"]').val().replace( /[^0-9\.]/g, '' );
        net_amount+= +(parseFloat(qty*price).toFixed(2));
        $('input[name="net_ammount"]').val('$'+ addCommas(parseFloat(net_amount).toFixed(2)));

    });
}
```

Now i want if net_amount is looks like -123225.32 then it show in input[name="net_ammount"] as ($123,225.32)

Comment: can you tell the exactly you want to do with little explanation

Comment: Can you please post some *real* JavaScript code we can take as starting point?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I've edited my question please read all that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my working attempt:

```
function addCommas(val2) {

    val2 = val2.toString(); // cast to a string

    // index of minus sign
    var negative = val2.indexOf('-');

    // org = original index of dot, make val an array; i should be above index of minus + 1; decrease i
    for (var i = org = val2.indexOf('.'), val2 = val2.split(""); i > negative + 1; i--) {

        // i difference between org and i is multiple of 3 and at the current index is a number
        if ((org - i) % 3 == 0 &&
            /[0-9]/.test(val2[org - i])) {
            // insert a `,` and decrease i
            val2.splice(i--, 0, ',');
        }
    }

    val2 = val2.join("");

  if(parseInt(val2, 10) >= 0) 
    return '$' + val2; 
  else 
    return '($' + val2 + ')';
}

alert(addCommas(123225.32)); // $123,225.32
alert(addCommas(-123225.32)); // ($123,225.32)

function remCommas(val){
  var pre = '';
  if(val.indexOf("(") > -1){
    pre = "$-";
    val = val.replace(/\(\$/, "").replace(/\)/, "");
  }
  val = pre + val;
  return val;
}

alert(remCommas('$123,225.32')); // $123,225.32
alert(remCommas('($123,225.32)')); // $-123,225.32
```

Comment: Hi gaurav this number is in currency format with thousand separator.

Comment: @SatendraMishra Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @gaurav thanks for reply dear but - sign is still not replaced and visible in alert

Comment: @SatendraMishra: Please read this author's name more closely.

Comment: @SatendraMishra I know my name's spelling s difficult. But StackOverflow gives automatic suggestions...

Comment: I'm sorry Gaurang, I could not read the names properly, because I'm also doing some other work. So please don't mind about this

Comment: @SatendraMishra Ok, I don't mind it, but I have now edited my answer according to your requirements.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Please wait while i've to check this

Comment: @GaurangTandon isme abhi bhi ek dikkat hai, agar val2 positive number ho jata hai to bhi brackets rahte hain. jabki inhe hat jana chahiye.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Please also tell how can reverse val2 to it's actual status means how can change ($123,225.32) to $-123,225.32

Comment: @SatendraMishra Done. In answer.